# Storing escape characters in unix variable

Tags: string, shell, variables, unix

I am extracting a part from an existing file and storing it as a string in a variable.The string looks something like this.

```
var="*a<br>*b<br>*c"
```

Now as * is a special character in unix it doesnot work in further operations(like sed,grep) until I put an escape character infront of every *

Thats why,I am doing something like this -

```
echo $var | sed 's/\*/\\*/g'
```

On running this command in bash we get

```
echo $var | sed 's/\*/\\*/g'

\*a<br>\*b<br>\*c
```

which is the desired output,but when I try to store this in a variable, I am getting back my original variable like so

```
var=`echo $var | sed 's/\*/\\*/g'`
echo $var

*a<br>*b<br>*c
```

I am assuming this happens because the variable ignores the backslashes interpreting them as escape characters. How can I retain the backslashes and store them as in a variable?

Comment: To the shell, backslashes are only special _as syntax_, not as data values. Once you store them in a string they're just another character. (That said, external programs -- like `sed` -- receive _data_ through their argument lists; they don't know what syntax was used to create that data)

Comment: Anyhow, the thing that actually causes your immediate problem is the backticks. Don't use them. The modern syntax for command substitution is `$( )`, and unlike backticks, it doesn't change how backslashes behave.

Comment: `echo $var` without quotes will cause all sorts of problems when `$var` contains shell meta characters.

Comment: From the bash man page: `When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, back-quote, or \.  The  first  back-quote  not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.`

Comment: Unix doesn't care about `*`. Various programs do: the shell treats it as a wild-card, regular expressions treat it as a zero-or-more operator applied to the preceding regular expression, etc. The need to escape it is dictated by the use you will put the string to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by backticks. Use `$( )` instead, and it goes away:

```
var="*a<br>*b<br>*c"
var=$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed 's/\*/\\*/g')
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

(*Why* is this problem caused by backticks? Because the only way to nest them is to escape the inner ones with backslashes, so they necessarily change how backslashes behave; whereas `$( )`, because it uses different starting and ending sigils, can be nested natively).

---

That said, if your shell is one (like bash) with ksh-inspired extensions, you don't need `sed` at all here, as the shell can perform  simple string replacements natively via [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
var="*a<br>*b<br>*c"
printf '%s\n' "${var//'*'/'\*'}"
```

---

For background on why this answer uses `printf` instead of `echo`, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) at [unix.se], or the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.